Assigning the Fold operator
I can define Sum as follows:
Sum ← +´

It works fine:
   Sum ⟨1, 2, 3⟩
6

I'd like to assign the Fold operator to a name:
Fold ← ´

However, I get the following:
   Fold ← ´
Error: Role of the two sides in assignment must match
at Fold ← ´
   ^^^^

Is there a way to setup such a definition?

` is a 1-modifier. It can be assigned as follows:
_fold ← ´

https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/doc/expression.html#role-spellings

(Thanks to dzaima who answered this on the bqn discord channel.)
